# Selenium - How to hide command prompt window

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to hide command prompt window when starting selenium chrome, but I can't figure it out.

**Here is my code:**

```
            var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
            driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

            var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.AddArguments("--headless");
    
            var browser = new ChromeDriver(driverService, chromeOptions);
```

But it crash on: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 85`

I tried to manually add path to driver but It crash's also.

**Different code I used**

```
            var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
            driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

            var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.AddArguments("--headless");
            chromeOptions.BinaryLocation = "C:\\Users\\TriX\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32";
    
            var browser = new ChromeDriver(driverService, chromeOptions)
```

Now it crash on: `OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'unknown error: Failed to create Chrome process.'`

Thanks for help I am completely lost :(

I tried different codes as shown, but without success.

Comment: The web driver and browser major versions needs to match. You appear to have ChromeDriver version 85, which only supports Chrome version 85. Download the correct version of driver for your browser version: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads/version-selection

Comment: Are you getting the chrome webdriver over the NuGet store? Which NuGet are you using? The Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver are always working fine for me (https://github.com/jsakamoto/nupkg-selenium-webdriver-chromedriver/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @r000bin i managed to resolve the problem. I also find out that I installed outdated version of ChromeDriver. So, I downloaded the correct one and it started to work.

1. I had old ChromeDrive nuget version
2. Downloaded the new one and uninstalled old one
3. Started to work :)